# Getting worse results after Hyperparameter Tuning(Grid/Random Search/TPOT)

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameter-tuning

I have a problem with Hyperparameter Tuning. Usually I getting almost the same results(or worse) than before tuning. Usually default parameters of classificator(regressor) give me a best score. Anybody could recommend other techniques or give me a tip what I should improve?